# ComboStore is not loading the data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I create a combobox with these are the configuration I given.

```
displayField: 'TEXT',
valueField: 'ID',
```

Here is my store

```
this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({

        url: 'combodata.json',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            rootProperty: 'ROOT.TAG'
        })
    }),
        fields: [
                    {name: 'ID', mapping: 'ID', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'TEXT', mapping: 'TEXT', type: 'string'}
                ],
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

And here is my JSON

```
{
    "ROOT": {
        "TAG": [{
            "ID": 01,
            "TEXT": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "ID": 02,
            "TEXT": "DEF"
        },
        {
            "ID": 03,
            "TEXT": "GHI"
        }]
    }
}
```

I can see URL is going into response and but data is not loading in combobox. Even data is not going to store itself.  Can anyone help me why data is not loading in combo.
**Update :**

```
this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: [
                    {name: 'ID', mapping: 'ID', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'TEXT', mapping: 'TEXT', type: 'string'}
                ],
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({

                url: 'adata.json',//this.url,
                headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    },
                actionMethods: {
                    read: 'GET'
                },
                reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    root: 'ROOT'
                })
            })
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked in console that whether combo is having store loaded or not by <comboElement>.getStore() method.Check in it what values are present

Comment: Store is loading but `store.data` having no items

Comment: @David please have a look for [queryMode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-queryMode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I made this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24r4), I'm loading the combo from a JSON file.

Notice that inside the `Assets` folder has the JSON file `data.json` that is loaded by the store.

As the Lorenz commented, it is necessary to make some changes, take a look, I hope I can help you!

Comment: Can you please make this into Ext 3

Comment: I do not have ExtJS 3, but if you know somewhere like fiddle.sencha.com, where you have a tool to develop, I can try.

Comment: @AlexandreNeukirchen this post is a year or so old, but I was hoping your fiddle worked, but for some reason it isn't loading the data, nor showing a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You tags indicate that you use ExtJs 3.4. `rootProperty` was not available in that version. Use `root` instead.

Also, I don't think that ExtJs 3.4 already allowed to specify a nested root like `root: 'ROOT.TAG'`, probably this is not possible an you have either to change the format of the JSON returned or upgrade to a newer version of ExtJs.

Try using this format with `root: 'ROOT'`:

```
{
    "ROOT": [{
        "ID": 01,
        "TEXT": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "ID": 02,
        "TEXT": "DEF"
    },
    {
        "ID": 03,
        "TEXT": "GHI"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I changed but no luck. What if I change my response like this..`<ROOT>
 <I ID="1" TEXT="AB1" />
 <I ID="2" TEXT="AB2" />
</ROOT>` In this case how I need to proceed.

Comment: You changed JSON to XML. I never used XML with ExtJs, so I cannot help for this. But I updated my answer indicating a JSON format that should work.

Comment: Sure. I update my code.. in question still no luck. I change to json again